# fullcalendar custom timeline view

Tags: fullcalendar, timeline

I'm looking for a way to create a view that can show multiple events that span across multiple days.  The screenshot below is what I'm trying to achieve.  Can someone suggest how this would be done using fullcalendar?
[desired look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8qrM.png)

Comment: it's not clear what you want. Are you asking how to do the vertical view of days? In which case you need to build a custom view as per the docs. And secondly "multiple events across multiple days". You can already have events across multiple days, trivially by setting the end date. Are you talking about a different way to show events that overlap each other?

Comment: I'm just starting out with fullcalendar so I'm not really sure where to start.  The image above is the look the designers what to achieve.  I looked through the examples on the fullcalendar.io site and I don't see any examples that are very close to my desired look.  What I'm looking for is some guidance on how to start to approach this using fullcalendar.

Comment: your approach of putting the days vertically rather than horizontally just doesn't exist. The available views by default are listed here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/ . The nearest thing to what you've shown is the "list" types of view - more here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/list_view/intro/ . But they only show days where events exist, and they don't show it in the grid format that you're after. As I already said, your main option if you definitely want something exactly like you've shown is to make a custom view: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/

Comment: Additionally, if you buy the premium "Scheduler" plugin, you have some extra options available to you, including the vertical versions of the "Timeline" views, which might be a bit closer to your desired approach, but it assumes that you can group your events by different "resources" - some sort of logical grouping of the events, either by location or something else. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical_resource_view/getting_started/ for an example. I suggest that you read all the docs through for yourself and see what suits you.